# What is the cleanest way to do a `std::partial_sum` with a `0` in front?

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, prefix-sum

In C++, there is a function `std::partial_sum` to compute prefix sum. The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::partial_sum(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

will override a to `1 3 6 10 15`, which is expected.

However, in most cases I want to use prefix sum, I want a `0` in front to indicate "empty sum" so that I can use `a[2] - a[0]` to query the sum of first two elements. (That allows me to use a trivial nested for loop to find sum of all subarrays). Is there a way to achieve it with the `std::partial_sum` function? I don't know if it will be possible since the output size will be input size + 1.

**Note: I am not seeking for ways that alters the content or type of `a` beforehand.**

If the size of `a` is a concern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1};
    std::partial_sum(a.begin(), a.end() - 1, a.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

Something like this can also work for me.

Comment: "so that I can use a[2] - a[0]" Then you are definitely going to want something else for your output iterator....

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Let's say I want to override the content of `a`

Comment: You can output to a different container just fine (and *because* you can, the different output size is not a problem). However, your original version of the code used `ostream_iterator`, which is not going to leave you with something where you can easily use `[]`. At any rate, the simplest workaround I can think of is to just output the `0` value to the iterator first, before passing it to `partial_sum`. `std::accumulate` lets you specify an initial value, but it just computes the final result rather than giving all the partial results.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel understood. Now what if I want to override `a` with `{0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15}` without another container? Would it be possible then?

Comment: I don't think that can work properly (even with e.g. an `insert_iterator` on a `std::vector`), because e.g. the initial `0` will overwrite the first value that you want to add, before it can be added to the running total.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That makes sense. I am expecting this to be not possible and just seeing if anyone can surprise me.

Comment: not sure about your note. you definitely alter the content of `a`?

Comment: @appleapple, yes the only requirement is the alteration is not before partial_sum.

Comment: "I am not seeking for ways that alters the content or type of a": are you serious ? The prefix sum does alter a and the result that you want *must* increase a's length !

Comment: @YvesDaoust please refresh your browser. I added the word "beforehand" a few minutes ago.

Comment: What difference does that make ? What is modifying before modifying ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well you can alter the content of `a`, just not before the `std::partial_sum()` operation

Comment: Prepend `0` after the prefix sum.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's exactly something I want to avoid.

Comment: Mh, you probably don't want to modify after modifying...

Comment: The logic of that is the same as prepending `0` beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve it with the `std::partial_sum` function?

Just write a 0 to the output iterator before calling `std::partial_sum`. Care should be taken as the output is one larger than the input, and this won't work in-place, as it writes the first output before reading the first input.

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
constexpr OutputIt my_partial_sum(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
    *d_first++ = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type{};
    return std::partial_sum(first, last, d_first);
}
```

If you want to be able to do it in place, you could adapt the [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum#Possible_implementation) of `std::partial_sum` further

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
constexpr OutputIt partial_sum(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;

    if (first == last) {
        *d_first++ = value_type{};
        return d_first;
    }

    value_type sum{};
    value_type next = *first;

    *d_first++ = sum;
 
    while (++first != last) {
       next = *first;
       sum = std::move(sum) + next;
       *d_first++ = sum;
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

but I think the simpler thing would be to prepend a 0 to your container.

```
template <typename Container>
void my_partial_sum(Container& c) {
    c.emplace(c.begin());
    std::partial_sum(c.begin(), std::prev(c.end()), c.begin());
}
```

Comment: Won't this break when overriding the input range?

Comment: @rubenvb the output is one larger than the input, but OP is aware of that

Comment: @Caleth It's not just the size, it's also that the first element is overwritten before it can be used by `partial_sum`. But the answer is already accepted, so OP seems to be aware that this solution cannot be used for naive in-place processing.

Comment: I was indeed talking about this replacing the first element of the input range before it's used by `std::partial_sum`, giving a different answer if it is not equal to the value initialized variable of the element type.

Comment: @j6t Yes thanks for pointing it out. In fact, I think I would stick to only prepending a `0` afterwards cause it's just one more statement.